# How Do I Save Screen Real Estate While Still Giving My Application The Power It Needs?

Tags: desktop-application, screen-real-estate

I've developed an application that throughout the stages has evolved twice.  The purpose of the application itself is display meaningful information in the smallest amount of space possible.  The "meaningful information" is variable so I wouldn't focus on it too much.  Here is a ruff layout of each version to date:

**Version 1**

[image]

**Version 2**

[image]

These pictures actually display the program to scale - so yes, they are pretty small.  I realized that I needed a way for users to load new content in easily so I included the "Load New Meaningful Information Button".  The problem I have with it is that it's location seems silly and it only needs to be visible when needed - not while the user is looking at the content and taking up space.  The other Caveat is that the application needs to be able to be resized easily.  I'm not worried so much about how much space the Meaningful Information Window takes up because it can be resized.  What I want to know is how to save as much real estate of your actual monitor.

[image]

I thought about making a version 3 of my application that would look like this:

[image]

The problem is that I then would have no way for my application to get dragged around, closed, or any ways for them to load new content.

I've thought about using the Task Trey but I want to make the application as intuitive as possible.  Are there any UX tricks out there that could solve a problem like this?  I've probably made this all sound really complicated so I hope it all makes sense.  If you have any questions, feel free to ask me in the comments.

Comment: The 'refresh' button could appear on mouseover only.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the third option (a window with no OS title bar) and add your own bar above your content which contains both a close button and a refresh button.

Answer (score 1):

So the answer should be as DA01 said

1. An refresh button when some one hovers over your window and as Danny Varod said
2. If you are deploying this on windows, then the third version should work as even through we have removed the window's borders, with some custom code you can get the window to move around when users drags it anywhere, let re size options come when he is at borders, add a close button etc